# How can I extract text in value in the example below in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a list of 1000 option like an example below and I need to extract text in the value. The desired result is 0012  –  Senior government managers and officials in the following case.

```
<option label="0012  –  Senior government managers and officials" value="0012  –  Senior government managers and officials"></option>
```

Comment: Are all 1000 entries containing both a `label` and a `value` and are they the same? If they aren't the same, then which would win?

Comment: All of the option have label and value but text is different. I need text from value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, where B2 is your string. This will extract everything between value=" and ".

`=MID(B2,FIND("value=",B2)+7,FIND(CHAR(34),B2,FIND("value=",B2)+7)-FIND("value=",B2)-7)`

Answer (score 0):

As one option you can use VBA where you can define a UDF:

```
Function getValues(html As String) As String
    getValues = Split(Split(html, "value")(1), """")(1)
End Function
```

And then call it in your workbook like a formula:

```
=getValues(A1)
```

Personally I find the option to split a string by a delimiter and pull out one of the values very handy so I would define this more generically:

```
Function strtok(instring As String, delim As String, position As Integer) As String
    strtok = Split(instring, delim)(position - 1)
End Function
```

And then formula out in the sheet would be a bit more complex:

```
=strtok(strtok(A1, "value", 2), """", 2)
```